# how to debug in sharepoint

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i have a problem when i do external list, if i viewed the external list in share point it shows:
**"***Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator***"**. 
so i searched how to solve this problem and i found many said i should to use the debugger. will i'm new in sharePoint and i don't know many about it, would please any one show me how to debug in sharePoint step by step.
i found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg599007.aspx
but i couldn't get some of the points how to do it. i'll be thankful for who will present the answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're debugging in your local dev environment, you can attach to w3wp.exe (or click the "Run" button in the Visual Studio project if using 2010 or 2013 templates).

Either way, you can often find information about the error that occurred either in the Windows Event Logs or in the SharePoint logs at "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions(some version number)\Logs".

You can also turn custom errors off and stack trace to true in the web.config file to see more detailed information about the error in the browser as soon as it happens. See here:
http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/12/sharepoint-webconfig-how-to-show-full.html